# Generate function which return property value of property

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

I am trying  to emit following:

This is struct which will be included as property to a dynamically emited class:

```
public struct GeoPoint
{
    public double? lat { get; set; }

    public double? lon { get; set; }
}
```

I have to emit following class:

```
public class GeoPointOwner
{
    public GeoPoint GeoPoint{get; set;}
    public double? Getlat ()
    {
        return GeoPoint.lat;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how properly emit method GeoPointOwner.Getlat

Here is my code:

```
var mbGet = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Getlat", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(double?), Type.EmptyTypes);
var genGet = mbGet.GetILGenerator();
genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
//getMethodInfo below is MethodInfo of Getter of GeoPoint property
genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getMethodInfo);
var getMethod = typeof(GeoPoint).GetProperty("lat").GetGetMethod(true);
//code emitted below fails when invoked
genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getMethod);
genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: “This is static class” Eh? It's neither static nor a class.

Comment: Have you tried running PEVerify on the generated code?

Comment: Also, are you aware that [mutable `struct`s are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/441323/41071)?

Comment: Yep it is "static" in a sense that it is not emitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in a comment, with errors like this, it's best to use PEVerify on the generated assembly. Using that on your code will help you fix it.

If I run it on the generated assembly, I get this error:

> [GeoPointOwner::Getlat][offset 0x00000006] Callvirt on a value type method.

You can't use `callvirt` to call a method on a value type (in your case, that's the getter for `GeoPoint.lat`), use `call` instead.

After fixing that, I get two new errors:

> [GeoPointOwner::Getlat][offset 0x00000006][found value 'ConsoleApplication1.GeoPoint'][expected address of value 'ConsoleApplication1.GeoPoint'] Unexpected type on the stack.
>
> [GeoPointOwner::Getlat][offset 0x0000000B] Unrecognized local variable number.

I'm going to first fix the second one. You're using `stloc_0`, which stores the value on the top of the stack to the local variable #0. It fails, because you didn't declare any locals. I don't understand why are you doing that, since you don't need any locals here. You can directly return the result of the `call`, so you can remove the `stloc_0`.

The first error is more complicated. When you want to call a method on a value type, you actually need a reference to a variable of that type. We don't have a variable right now, which means we have to create one (using `DeclareLocal()`), save the value to a local (`stloc`) and then load the address of that local (`ldloca`). For some more information, see the question *[Method invocation on a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5895458/41071)*.

With those changes, your code becomes something like:

```
var getlatBuilder = type.DefineMethod("Getlat", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(double?), Type.EmptyTypes);
var il = getlatBuilder.GetILGenerator();
var getPointLocal = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(GeoPoint));

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, geoPointGetter);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, getPointLocal);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, getPointLocal);

var latGetter = typeof(GeoPoint).GetProperty("lat").GetGetMethod(true);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, latGetter);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: Tx dudde for solving that puzzle for me!